# Licence error while using Liquibase Migrations in Java Application

Tags: java, migration, liquibase

I have java application created using Dropwizard framework, where I have used liquibase migrations. I am able to run "db migrate" command from eclipse but same command fails from terminal cli.

I have been trying to find error in my settings for long, but now I need some help from liquibase experts. Here is the error log printed. Please let me know - what could be wrong.

```
OS : MAC OS X
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

java -jar target/code.jar db migrate src/main/resources/code-local.yml                                    
INFO  [2015-09-07 11:36:00,288] liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO  [2015-09-07 11:36:07,866] liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Exception in thread "main" liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: /var/folders/7y/3wfpy71x4j779d854h_g_h48zrgjtv/T/liquibase-unzip3153640369191170689.dir/license/LICENSE (Not a directory)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:215)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbMigrateCommand.run(DbMigrateCommand.java:57)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbCommand.run(DbCommand.java:52)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.AbstractLiquibaseCommand.run(AbstractLiquibaseCommand.java:63)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:73)
    at com.x.y.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:39)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: /var/folders/7y/3wfpy71x4j779d854h_g_h48zrgjtv/T/liquibaseunzip3153640369191170689.dir/license/LICENSE (Not a directory)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:334)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:264)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:211)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/7y/3wfpy71x4j779d854h_g_h48zrgjtv/T/liquibase-unzip3153640369191170689.dir/license/LICENSE (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at liquibase.util.FileUtil.unzip(FileUtil.java:76)
    at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.list(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:316)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try adding the Liquibase library folder to the class path as well?

```
java -jar liquibase.jar;lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar;target/code.jar db migrate src/main/resources/code-local.yml
```

I have mentioned the jar file names for the liquibase 3.4.1 version. Change as per your setup.

Comment: Thanks Ayusman for replying. My project is a maven project and I have added dependency for "dropwizard-migrations" in pom.xml.  This in turn brings liquibase dependency. Should I add liquibase dependency as well in pom.xml

Comment: Added "liquibase-core" in pom.xml and created fat jar. This did not help recover from license error

Comment: did you unzip the liquibase distribution properly. Try adding liquibase root folder to classpath as well, like 
java -jar .;liquibase.jar;lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar;target/code.jar db migrate src/main/resources/code-local.yml

Comment: Since you are on Mac OSX, use : as the classpath separator I guess

Comment: Are you using the liquibase-xyz.zip file directly in the classpath? Instead try unzipping the zip file to a folder of your choice and then try, do you still face the same issue?

Comment: Need some time to test proposed solution. Will update back in couple of hours

Comment: Issue solved. Mine was shaded jar and had to exclude one dependency "xml-apis" that brought LICENCE files that were not processed by Liquibase unzip method.

Comment: @Deepak your comment should be an answer and the accepted one. It solve my issue.